# Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::getGraphNode()

Tags: php, facebook

I am getting the following error:

> Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::getGraphNode()

From this code:

```
    $params = array();

    try {
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
        $response = $facebook->request('GET', '/123456789/feed', $params,'fgj123fgj123fgj');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();


    print_r($graphNode);
```

The line:

```
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

Is taken directly from their docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0

Any Solutions so I can get the data returned correctly?

Comment: Have you imported the sdk ?

Comment: If I hadn't, it would have failed a lot earlier in the code

Comment: _“The line: `$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();` Is taken directly from their docs”_ - yeah, but in that example `$response` is something different. And your comment, `// Returns a Facebook\FacebookResponse object`, is simply wrong. No, it does _not_  return a FacebookResponse object.

Comment: @Zl3n can you post your full code?

Comment: @Zl3n access token is set after params

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace **`->request()`** by **`->get()`** like this (according to your example) :

```
$response = $facebook->get('GET', '/123456789/feed', $params,'fgj123fgj123fgj');
```

Like written in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0) :

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(\* *\);
// Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
$response = $fb->get('/something');
```